# How do I stop my hamburger icon from staying with top bar so it appears with the side menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
.hamburger
```

stays with my top bar which is hidden if I change the z-index,
how do I stop this from happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/g3nn0cvy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please add a [mcve] to your question - a link-only question is not enough since the link can become obsolete making the question incomplete and impossible to answer.

Comment: assuming you want to make the nav icon scroll with the page?

Comment: that's a whooole lot of css for that... decent effect though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the topbar to be hidden when the menu is open, and have the hamburger appear on top of the menu while it is open.

Use css `visibility: hidden` on your `#heading`, and set `visibility: visible` on your `.hamburger`, don't change z-indexes.

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3nn0cvy/2/) with an example